# C++ generic type of generic type

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I'm trying to build a generic matrix based on a generic vector that I've already built.  I want to have a vector of vectors (each internal vector represents a row).  For some reason, this isn't working:

```
template <typename T>
class matrix : vector<vector<T>>{...}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
error: 'class vector<T>' is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter
```

I tried looking into template templates, but couldn't really understand how to make them work.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: cannot reproduce: [link](https://ideone.com/ntbsCA), please provide a minimal, verifiable sample that exhibits this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class matrix : public std::vector<std::vector<T>>
{
};

int main()
{
    matrix<int> m;

    m.push_back({});
    m[0].push_back(0);
    m[0].push_back(1);
    m[0].push_back(2);

    m.push_back({});
    m[1].push_back(3);
    m[1].push_back(4);
    m[1].push_back(5);

    m.push_back({});
    m[2].push_back(6);
    m[2].push_back(7);
    m[2].push_back(8);

    return 0;
}
```

However I suggest investigating "[A proper way to create a matrix in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618511/a-proper-way-to-create-a-matrix-in-c)" topic which looks very close to what your want to implement.

Comment: Please change return type of main from `void` to `int`. Otherwise, compilation fails. Try your code on Wandbox. https://wandbox.org/permlink/w1sJ8gxwZPPqaQMS

Comment: `return 0;` is missing.

Comment: @KunalPuri, fixed. Thanks!